Solana blink returns Unable to confirm transaction
I created a P2P SPL swap application using an escrow smart contract and added a blink feature. Basically, whoever creates the escrow will get a blink to complete the escrow token swap. They can then share the blink with whoever they want to swap with. My issue is that if I take this link and sign it with another wallet on https://dial.to, the transaction never confirms. I get an "Unable to confirm transaction" error. There are no logs on the console either. Furthermore, if I take the escrow address and check the latest transaction associated with it on explorer, I see that the transaction has actually succeeded and the swap has taken place. It is just with dialect that I'm unable to confirm the transaction. I'm placing my route.ts code below.
import {
  ActionGetResponse,
  ActionPostRequest,
  ActionPostResponse,
  ACTIONS_CORS_HEADERS,
} from "@solana/actions";

import {
  clusterApiUrl,
  Connection,
  PublicKey,
  SystemProgram,
  Keypair
} from "@solana/web3.js";
import { AnchorProvider, Program } from "@coral-xyz/anchor";
import { IDL } from "@/app/solana/idl";
import {
  ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
  getAssociatedTokenAddressSync,
  TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
} from "@solana/spl-token";
import NodeWallet from "@coral-xyz/anchor/dist/cjs/nodewallet";

const DEFAULT_SOL_ADDRESS = "5o3x9hBMDeLe3LYw7PKnyGiBD7LhroMFxt4LS2eoydR1";
const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"), "finalized");

export async function GET(req: Request, res: Response) {
  const responseBody: ActionGetResponse = {
    icon: "https://example.com/icon.png",
    title: "Toekn.",
    description: "Swap SPL tokens on Solana.",
    label: "Accept Trade",
  };

  const response = Response.json(responseBody, {
    headers: ACTIONS_CORS_HEADERS,
  });
  return response;
}

export async function POST(req: Request, res: Response) {
  const postReq: ActionPostRequest = await req.json();
  const userKey = postReq.account;
  const requestUrl = new URL(req.url);
  const { escrow, mintA, mintB, maker } = await validatedQueryParams(requestUrl);

  let wallet = new NodeWallet(new Keypair());
  const provider = new AnchorProvider(connection, wallet);
  const program = new Program(IDL, provider);


  const vault = getAssociatedTokenAddressSync(
    mintA,
    escrow,
    true,
    TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
  );

  const takerAtaA = getAssociatedTokenAddressSync(
    mintA,
    new PublicKey(userKey),
    true,
    TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
  );

  const takerAtaB = getAssociatedTokenAddressSync(
    mintB,
    new PublicKey(userKey),
    true,
    TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
  );

  const makerAtaB = getAssociatedTokenAddressSync(
    mintB,
    maker,
    true,
    TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
  );

  const tx = await program.methods
    .take()
    .accountsPartial({
      taker: userKey,
      maker,
      mintA,
      mintB,
      takerAtaA: takerAtaA,
      takerAtaB: takerAtaB,
      makerAtaB: makerAtaB,
      escrow,
      vault,
      associatedTokenProgram: ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
      tokenProgram: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
      systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId,
    })
    .transaction();

  const blockhash = (await connection.getLatestBlockhash()).blockhash;
  tx.recentBlockhash = blockhash;
  tx.feePayer = new PublicKey(userKey);

  const serialTx = tx
    .serialize({ requireAllSignatures: false, verifySignatures: false })
    .toString("base64");

  const responseBody: ActionPostResponse = {
    transaction: serialTx,
    message: "Trade Completed.",
  };

  const response = Response.json(responseBody, {
    headers: ACTIONS_CORS_HEADERS,
  });

  return response;
}

export async function OPTIONS(req: Request, res: Response) {
  return new Response(null, { headers: ACTIONS_CORS_HEADERS });
}

async function validatedQueryParams(requestUrl: URL) {
  let escrow: PublicKey = new PublicKey(DEFAULT_SOL_ADDRESS);
  let maker: PublicKey = new PublicKey(DEFAULT_SOL_ADDRESS);
  let mintA: PublicKey = new PublicKey(DEFAULT_SOL_ADDRESS);
  let mintB: PublicKey = new PublicKey(DEFAULT_SOL_ADDRESS);

  try {
    if (requestUrl.searchParams.get("escrow")) {
      escrow = new PublicKey(requestUrl.searchParams.get("escrow")!);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    throw "Invalid input query parameter: escrow";
  }

  try {
    if (requestUrl.searchParams.get("maker")) {
      maker = new PublicKey(requestUrl.searchParams.get("maker")!);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    throw "Invalid input query parameter: maker";
  }

  try {
    if (requestUrl.searchParams.get("mintA")) {
      mintA = new PublicKey(requestUrl.searchParams.get("mintA")!);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    throw "Invalid input query parameter: mintA";
  }

  try {
    if (requestUrl.searchParams.get("mintB")) {
      mintB = new PublicKey(requestUrl.searchParams.get("mintB")!);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    throw "Invalid input query parameter: mintB";
  }

  return {
    maker,
    escrow,
    mintA,
    mintB,
  };
}



are you connected to devent on the wallet and on dial.to?

Yes, I'm connected to devnet, still doesn't go through

After spending a lot of time trying to figure it out, I realised that I hadn't connected to devnet on dial.to (as nickfrosty rightly pointed out). This one's on me :p
